# Web API POST method for Tables with Relationship

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Web API.
I am creating web API POST method for Order. in which two tables I have created
1)Tbl_Order have columns- Order_ID -Primary Key, Employee_ID, TotalBill,

2)Tbl_OrderMenu have columns- OrderMenuID -Primary Key, Order_ID -Foreign Key from Tbl_Order, MenuName, Quantity

the relationship between tables is one-to-many i.e. Tbl_Order(1)-to-Tbl_OrderMenu(* or Many).

How can I create Web API to POST method to create Data at the same time?

```
public class myCombinedClass
{
 public int Order_ID {get;set;}
 public int Employee_ID {get;set;}
 public string TotalBill {get;set;}
 public List<Tbl_OrderMenu> OrderMenu { get; set; }
}
```

My API POST controller is

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(myCombinedClass myData)
{
 if(myData.id == 0)
  {
    // This is a new entry to Tbl_Order.
  }
 else
  {
   //You just need to update the Tbl_Order. I mean, here you are adding 
   //data to Tbl_OrderMenu table with  Order_ID.
  }
}
```

What will come in POST method.

Comment: Huh? There isn't magic voodoo.  Once you (successfully) get the myCombinedClass "across the wire" and into the method" ("Post" in this case)...you gotta do something with it.  Either use Entity-Framework or Ado.Net or something to get it into the db (I guess that's what you mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@manish, here is an example of the POST method using EF:

```
// POST: api/myCombinedClasses
[ResponseType(typeof(myCombinedClass))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostmyCombinedClass(myCombinedClass mycombinedclass)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.myCombinedClasses.Add(mycombinedclass);
    db.OrderMenus.AddRange(mycombinedclass.OrderMenu);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = mycombinedclass.Order_ID }, mycombinedclass);
}
```